# A question on the rotational motion of a metal drinking cup

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

When I rotate a metal drinking cup slowly it rotates normally. However, when I rotated the cup with a much greater speed, the cup's body started to rise and was rotating with a small portion of its base touching the ground (I recommend you do this to understand what I mean).
Can somebody explain why this happens?

Comment: It might be due to friction. The ground applies a force opposite to the one you are applying and it generates a torque that makes it rotate along some axis